# How to dump only create table statements (or table definitions only) with pg_dump in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want only the table definitions, not wiews nor functions.

I have a schema named "cvp". I try:

```sh
    pg_dump --schema-only -n cvp -t 'cvp.*' --format plain
```

And I get:

```
pg_dump: No matching tables were found
```

I try also without `-n cvp` or changing `-t` to `-t *.*` `-t cvp`.

I'am using PostgreSQL 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried this:

```
pg_dump -s -t test.* -d test
```

It nicely exported all table definitions, as expected.  `-s` is the same as `--schema-only`.

Comment: But it also dumps the views.

Comment: My problem was other. I put the `-t test.*` in a variable in windows. Then when I use it wihtout single-quotes it expands to files in the file system. When I use it with single quotes `-t 'test.*'` it does not works and say me `pg_dump: No matching tables were found`